# Open my app when an nfc tag of a custom format is discovered

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nfc, intentfilter

I'm making an app for stock management. Each stock_item will have a tag, with a unique identifier, with a custom_format.
Like this:

```
stock_manager_pro:stock_item:12345
```

or

```
stock_manager_pro:user:john
```

I want to make my app open automatically when the device discovers a tag with whose content that starts with **stock_manager_pro**

With this code my apps its opened when the phone discovers a nfc tag with plain/text content, but I want to be able to filter customer texts.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I've just found a way to perform this. I create a tag with an URI content. Instead of writting a http:// address, I set the URI to stock_manager_pro://stock_item/1234.

Then, in the manifest, i apply this URI filter: <data android:scheme="stock_manager_pro"/>

For me its enough, since I can decide the content of the tags, but if I couldn't change the tag content, anyone knows a way to perform the same with text/plain tags?

Comment: You might want to check out Android Application Record

Answer (score 3):

I m working on same problem...
I Found that you should make your own Custom MIME type.
and in manifest file You should simply remove

```
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
```

eg

```
<intent-filter >
   <!--  <action   android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />-->
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.nfctagwriter" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own mime type and it doesn't have to have the fully qualified "application" at the begining. It also understands "app/customname" .. this is useful for keeping the data size small.

For example stack overflow mime type could be "app/so" instead of "application/stackoverflow".

Although I guess it depends how likely you feel someone else would be using "app/so". In our case it doesn't matter because we are only using it internally.